# Trying to get the status of firebase user authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an authentication function using firebase which is just the auth code from the firebase documentation

```js
export const signIn = (email,password) => {
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(()=>{
       alert('Sign in Successful!')
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error.message)
    });
}
```

I call it like this

```
signIn(mail, password)
```

When I call it in my code, It works perfectly and the proper alerts appear. However, I want to actually receive something from my authentication function, like True or False if the user successfully logged in or not. Is there a way for me to receive this value from my function or any workarounds?

```
//evaluates to True if logged in successfully and vice versa
let authState = signIn(this.mail, this.password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple approaches you could take with this, the first that comes to mind is the following:

```js
export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userCredential => {
    alert('Sign in Successful!');
    return true;
  }).catch(error => {
    alert(error.message);
    return false;
  });
}

// ......

let authState = await signIn(this.mail, this.password);
```

In `promises` you're able to `return` values from the `.then()` or `.catch()` method and then use that resolved value further in your code.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Is the response in the .then() required? It seems to work when I leave it out

Comment: No it's not required, I just prefer to have my callbacks appropriately named rather than leaving it empty. If any of the given answers solved your problem, remember to mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a user is signed in, no matter how they were signed in, you should instead use an auth state observer to set up a callback that will be invoked whenever the user becomes signed in or out, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```

Comment: The issue in my use case is that when the user signs in, I want to be able to edit variables out of the scope of the function you provided, which I can't really do with this setup.

Comment: You can certainly use some form of data sharing or dependency injection to act on the user object outside the scope of the callback.  Fact of the matter is that auth state observers are the preferred way of hooking signin and signout state, and are used like this on all platforms.  Yes, it does change the shape of your program, but this kind of asynchronous "reactive" programming is the new normal.